# Java error in declaring array in random

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
class random
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n[];
        Random rand=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            int n[i]=rand.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The random number is::"+n[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i get while compiling:

[image: error]

I have no idea can anyone please help.

Comment: Use `int n[] = new int[11];` and `n[i] = rand.nextInt();`

Comment: thanks a lot bro !!

Answer (score 1):

// first you need to declare the size for the `n` array

```
int n[] = new int [11];  // needs to be 11
Random rand=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    n[i]=rand.nextInt();  // and then just assign
    System.out.println("The random number is::"+n[i]);
}
```

**but** to be honest you do not even need this array in this code as it is not being re-used

More simpler would be

```
Random rand=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    System.out.println("The random number is::" + rand.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: I don't know who this person *bro* is but, have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]) - also please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your array. See link for an example.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

```
n = new int[11];
```

before the for loop should do it.

Thanks for the catch wombat

Comment: as the OP is using `for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)` you need `int [11]]`

Answer (score 0):

try this thing...

```
import java.util.Random;
class random
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] n= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
                Random rand=new Random();
                n[i]=rand.nextInt();
                System.out.println("The random number is::"+n[i]);
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: why would you do `int[] n= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};` ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, suppose we want to use array we can use in two ways:

1. As a variable where you need to define fixed size first otherwise you will get **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**:

   int[] id = new int[size fo array];

example : -

`

```
import java.util.Random;
class random
{    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // here first you need to initilized the array with fixed sizea
        int n[] = new int[11];
        Random rand=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            n[i]=rand.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The random number is::"+n[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

`

2. As an Argument of the method where you need not define the fixed size:
   the best example is a command line argument

For execution below code, you need to pass command line argument at runtime.

`

```
   import java.util.Random;
    class random
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println(args[0] + args[1]);
        }
    }
```

`